# AttributeError: 'Tank' object has no attribute 'hit'

Tags: python

I'm trying to practice the following code from the book "Beginning Python Games Development, Second Edition: With PyGame".

```
class Tank(object):

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name
        self.alive = True
        self.ammo = 5
        self.armor = 60

    def __str__(self):

        if self.alive:
            return "%s (%i armor and %i shells left)" % (self.name, self.armor, self.ammo)
        else:
            return "%s is DEAD !" % self.name

    def fire_at(self, enemy):

        if self.ammo >= 1:
            self.ammo -= 1
            print(self.name, " fires on ", enemy.name)
            enemy.hit()
        else:
            print(self.name, " has no shells!")

        def hit(Self):

            self.armor -= 20
            print(self.name, " is hit !")
            if self.armor <= 0:
                self.explode()

        def explode(self):

            self.alive = False
            print(self.name, " explodes !!!!")
```

---

```
from tank import Tank

tanks = {"a": Tank("Alice"), "b": Tank("Bob"), "c": Tank("Crane"), "d": Tank("Paula"), "e": Tank("Paulo")}
alive_tanks = len(tanks)

while alive_tanks > 1:

    for tank_name in sorted(tanks):
        print(tank_name, tanks[tank_name])

    first = input("Who fires ?").lower()
    second = input("Who at ?").lower()

    try:
        first_tank = tanks[first]
        second_tank = tanks[second]
    except KeyError as name:
        print("No such Tank!", name)
        continue

    if not first_tank.alive or not second_tank.alive:
        print("One of those is dead!")
        continue

    print("*"*30)

    first_tank.fire_at(second_tank)
    if not second_tank.alive:
        alive_tanks -= 1

    print("*"*30)

    for tank in tanks.value():
        if tank.alive:
            print(tank.name, " is the winner !")
            break
```

But there is a problem: `AttributeError: 'Tank' object has no attribute 'hit'.`

Can someone please explain what is happening?

Comment: Is this the actual indentation? As it is here, `hit` is inside of the `fire_at` method, which means it isn't a method of `Tank`.

Comment: also, it's good to fix `Self` to `self`

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation problem. In Python you can define functions inside other functions to support closures so this is why your code is syntactically correct. The correct code is:

```
class Tank(object):

   def __init__(self, name):

       self.name = name
       self.alive = True
       self.ammo = 5
       self.armor = 60

   def __str__(self):

       if self.alive:
           return "%s (%i armor and %i shells left)" % (self.name, self.armor, self.ammo)
       else:
           return "%s is DEAD !" % self.name

   def fire_at(self, enemy):

       if self.ammo >= 1:
           self.ammo -= 1
           print(self.name, " fires on ", enemy.name)
           enemy.hit()
       else:
           print(self.name, " has no shells!")

   def hit(self):

       self.armor -= 20
       print(self.name, " is hit !")
       if self.armor <= 0:
           self.explode()

   def explode(self):
       self.alive = False
       print(self.name, " explodes !!!!")
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
With this suggestion I was able to find another error in the code, related to indentation too.